# Select rows with the highest ID and a speciefied column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with a sql query. I have the following table:

```
╔════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║     NAME      ║    CITY     ║ PCNUMBER ║
╠════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ John Doe      ║ New York    ║       42 ║
║  2 ║ John Doe      ║ New York    ║       42 ║
║  3 ║ John Doe      ║ New York    ║       42 ║
║  4 ║ John Doe      ║ Los Angeles ║       42 ║
║  5 ║ Ellen Ripley  ║ Nostromo    ║     2092 ║
║  6 ║ James T. Kirk ║ Riverside   ║     2233 ║
║  7 ║ Henry Jones   ║ Chicago     ║     1899 ║
╚════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

Now I would like to get the rows that have the specified PCNUMBER (can be more than 1) but it can only return 1 result for each unique PCNUMBER

So let's assume I want the data from PCNUMBER 42 and 2092. The result would be:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║     NAME     ║    CITY     ║ PCNUMBER ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║  4 ║ John Doe     ║ Los Angeles ║       42 ║
║  5 ║ Ellen Ripley ║ Nostromo    ║     2092 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

I've tried numerous things but I can't seem to produce this :( Hope you guys can help me.

I'm sorry if someone already had a similar question but I couldn't find one.

Comment: how would you decide what city value to use i.e. John Doe has New York and Los Angeles.

Comment: L.A as it has the highest ID I presume given the title

Comment: @tomasmcguinness: it's in the title: "with the highest ID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server supports `Common Table Expression` and `Windowing Functions`.

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, Name, City, PCNUMBER,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PCNUMBER ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  ID, Name, City, PCNUMBER
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1 AND
        PCNUMBER IN (42, 2092)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1eb85/2)
- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║     NAME     ║    CITY     ║ PCNUMBER ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║  4 ║ John Doe     ║ Los Angeles ║       42 ║
║  5 ║ Ellen Ripley ║ Nostromo    ║     2092 ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

One way;

```
select T.* from T
    inner join (
        select 
            max(id) id
        from T
        where PCNUMBER in (42, 2092)
        group by PCNUMBER
    ) mx on mx.id = T.id
```